# Selecting specific joined record from findAll() with a hasMany() include

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfc, cfwheels

(I tried posting this to the CFWheels Google Group (twice), but for some reason my message never appears. Is that list moderated?)

Here's my problem: I'm working on a social networking app in CF on Wheels, not too dissimilar from the one we're all familiar with in Chris Peters's awesome tutorials. In mine, though, I'm required to display the most recent status message in the user directory. I've got a User model with hasMany("statuses") and a Status model with belongsTo("user"). So here's the code I started with:

```
users = model("user").findAll(include="userprofile, statuses");
```

This of course returns one record for every status message in the statuses table. Massive overkill. So next I try:

```
users = model("user").findAll(include="userprofile, statuses", group="users.id");
```

Getting closer, but now we're getting the first status record for each user (the lowest status.id), when I want to select for the most recent status. I think in straight SQL I would use a subquery to reorder the statuses first, but that's not available to me in the Wheels ORM. So is there another clean way to achieve this, or will I have to drag a huge query result or object the statuses into my CFML and then filter them out while I loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the most recent status using a [calculated property](http://cfwheels.org/docs/chapter/calculated-properties):

```
// models/User.cfc
function init() {
    property(
        name="mostRecentStatusMessage",
        sql="SELECT message FROM statuses WHERE userid = users.id ORDER BY createdat DESC LIMIT 1,1"
    );
}
```

Of course, the syntax of the `SELECT` statement will depend on your RDBMS, but that should get you started.

The downside is that you'll need to create a calculated property for each column that you need available in your query.

The other option is to create a method in your model and write custom SQL in `<cfquery>` tags. That way is perfectly valid as well.

Comment: Hey Chris. Thanks a ton for the response (and for generally making CFW accessible to the rest of us!). The property() solution is a good start (that was staring me in the face), but as written it just gets the most recent status ever, once. I need the most recent status for each user, where applicable (some have no statuses at all).

Comment: Sorry about that. Does my edit work where I add the `WHERE` clause to the subquery?

Comment: Well, I tried that before my last response, but all it does is get the message for the first record. I have 4 test users with records in users and userprofiles. Two of them have at least one status posted; the other two have none. The status is only getting grabbed for user.id = 1, so presumably the first one checked. After that, I get a "" value returned for all 3 other users' statuses.

Comment: Try to dump the query you're getting back and see what kind of SQL it's running. In theory, my code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact DB schema, but shouldn't your findAll() look more like something such as this:

```
statuses = model("status").findAll(include="userprofile(user)", where="userid = users.id");
```

That should get all statuses from a specific user...or is it that you need it for all users? I'm finding your question a little tricky to work out. What is it you're exactly trying to get returned?